# GPT4All could not load model due to invalid format for <name>.gguf

Tags: windows-10

Following the guideline I loaded GPT4All [Windows Desktop Chat Client](https://gpt4all.io/index.html) 2.6.0 and loaded models from its download section.

None of available models (I tried all of them) work with the message:

> Model loading error...
> Encountered an error loading model:
> "Could not load model due to invalid format for .gguf"

I tried loading the files from browser, as well. The files are identical with loaded by client. No available model works with the same message.

My system:

- Windows 10 x64, 64 GB RAM
- NVIDIA RTX 2080 Super, 8GB RAM

What could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/issues/1755) the error you received?

Comment: @Ramhound, as I stated in the question, "neither of models work" with this message. I tried all of them and double checked with downloading via browser and MD5 checking.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, this is exactly the message I get for all the models.

Comment: @Ramhound, "my" "neither of models" means "neither of available", so I opened the https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/issues/1822, hope this would help

Comment: You mean none of the avaiable models, "neither of the avaiable models" isn't proper english, and the source of my cnfusion.  Any event: "Back up your .ini file in <user-folder>\AppData\Roaming\nomic.ai and let it create a fresh one with a restart. If you had a different model folder, adjust that but leave other settings at their default. See if that changes anything."

Comment: @Ramhound, thank you for the catch, I fixed the grammar, of course I meant "None of". On the nomic.ai. Are you sure you mean the <user-folder>\AppData\Roaming\nomic.ai where only a couple files (GPT4All.ini, models.json) stored and not the <user-folder>\AppData\Local\nomic.ai, where in the GPT4All folder stored all the models and the database? I removed the former; nothing changed. I got the welcome screen and the error message straight over it. Should I try with the folder with models and database?

Comment: @Ramhound, tried removing both folders. Downloaded a couple of models (Mistral OpenOrca, Orca2 (Medium). Nothing changed. The same issue.

Comment: I meant the directory I suggested, taken from instructions (hence the quote), of a response to a GitHub issue.

Comment: @Ramhound, they provided the answer in the https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/issues/1822. Thank you for your help, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Per the https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/issues/1822, the 2.6.0 release has been reverted.

After re-installing to the 2.5.4 (the latest available at the https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/releases/) everything runs fine.